# Ms access DB - merge two tables base on columns

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to merge two tables in one base on:

```
app.custid = fin.custid and
app.appdate = fin.findate and
app.price = fin.pricx
```

and what is not equal to create a new table. This two tables have no relationship.

```
Table app
appid   custid    appdate    price   
1         1       10/10/20     20    
2         2       10/10/20     10    
3         1       11/10/20     30    
4         3       12/10/20     20    
5         1       13/10/20     20    


Table fin
finid   custid    findate    pricex     
1         1       10/10/20     20
2         2       11/10/20     10
3         1       11/10/20     20
4         3       12/10/20     20
5         1       13/10/20     20
```

Derire output:

```
Table app-new
appid   custid    appdate    price    pricex
1         1       10/10/20     20       20     => same custid, appdate=findate, price=pricex
2         2       10/10/20     10       null   => same custid, appdate not the same findate
3         1       11/10/20     30       null   => same custid, appdate=findate, price is not the same pricex
4         3       12/10/20     20       20     => same custid, appdate=findate, price=pricex
5         1       13/10/20     20       20     => same custid, appdate=findate, price=pricex

Table fin-new
finid   custid    findate    pricex   
2         2       11/10/20     10
3         1       11/10/20     20
```

Comment: Are you after a **query** that will give you these results for use in other software or other queries - or do you actually want to **copy** the output data into a new physical table in your Access DB file?

Comment: @Dai where ever is easier and correct. query or table is the same as i am stack...

Comment: What about appid and finid? Shouldn't they also match?

Comment: @forpas no match. Only the 3 columns i am explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st case you need a `LEFT` join of `app` to `fin`:

```
SELECT a.*, f.pricex
FROM app AS a LEFT JOIN fin AS f
ON f.custid = a.custid AND f.findate = a.appdate AND f.pricex = a.price
```

and for the 2nd case you can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM fin AS f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM app AS a 
  WHERE f.custid = a.custid AND f.findate = a.appdate AND f.pricex = a.price
)
```

or with a `LEFT` join of `fin` to `app` that filters out the matched rows:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM fin AS f LEFT JOIN app AS a
ON f.custid = a.custid AND f.findate = a.appdate AND f.pricex = a.price
WHERE a.appid IS NULL
```

Comment: In case 1, if i want to add WHERE a.workid = 21 or 22 how can i add it. WorkID is only in app table.  The case 1 is working the rest. I will test case 2.

Comment: @PeterPan2020 you can add at the end of the query: `WHERE a.workid IN (21, 22)`

Comment: @forbas and if want to added as AND a.workid = 21 or 22. Extra column from table app not in table fin. All conditions plus one from table app.

Comment: You can add as many conditions you want in the WHERE clause for the table app but not for table fin.

Comment: @forbas SELECT a.*, f.pricex
FROM app AS a LEFT JOIN fin AS f
ON f.custid = a.custid AND f.findate = a.appdate AND f.pricex = a.price AND a.workid=21 this i mean.

Comment: Access does not support such conditions in the ON clause. Put it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @forbas Ok. So will create this column to fin new table and them this new table simple match it with the case 1st. `SELECT f.*, WorkID(case when f.PriceLaser >0 then 21 else 0 end)
FROM tblFinances AS f` i am getting an error in where trying to create a new table fin with extra column

Comment: Access does not support CASE expressions. Us `IIF()`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3, but I don't understand why you can't use a WHERE clause.

Comment: @forbas Because i will run multiple times the same things but with different conditions. In the end i will have my desire output. So, i will start with table fin with 15k and every time it will became smaller.

Comment: These conditions are better to be applied in a WHERE clause. Access has special features/restrictions.